# Rogue header and page number in Word 2016 lands in the text area and won't go away (Track Changes?)

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, tracking, field-codes, bug

Working in a Microsoft Word 2016 document. Track Changes has been on through a couple of saved versions of this document. I noticed that a header, including its page number field code, has appeared inside the text area. Trying to delete it seems impossible: I turned on Show/Hide (Ctrl-*) and went into Draft Mode and turned off Track Changes and tried to carefully select the unwanted content and none of these seemed to work. There were always some codes remaining that did not show up even with "Show codes" activated. I also closed and re-opened the document. Free text can be deleted, but no amount of selection and character deletion will remove the field code.

Does anyone have more information?

Rogue header appearing inside running text in Microsoft Word 2016

[image: screenshot]

I'm very curious how the header got misplaced in the first place, and if this bug is repeatable. I suspect it may have to do with the way Track Changes' journal indexes the objects that get cut and paste or otherwise moved, that perhaps I cut and pasted across a page break at one time, with certain settings (Show Markup settings?). Word's cursor behavior here is often a little unpredictable, which is why I suppose it might be related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a provisional solution, but I would still like to know if anyone has more information on this bug or a better solution.

I saved a copy, reopened the file, turned off Track Changes, selected and deleted the text, and this seemed to solve the problem. I don't know if the new Track Changes session did the trick or the fresh file. Anyone know?

Comment: This should be included as an edit to your question, not as an Answer.

Comment: All in good time.